# DataGrid enums not showing correctly using DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a simple DataGrid with an ItemSource pointing to a DataTable.

DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TableDG" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Background="{x:Null}"/>
```

C#

```
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MinHeight = 400;
        this.MinWidth = 600;
        TableDG.CanUserAddRows = true;
        TableDG.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        Table = new DataTable();
        Table.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));
        Table.Columns.Add("Tipo", typeof(TestEnumTypes));
        TableDG.ItemsSource = Table.AsDataView();
        TableDG.CanUserAddRows = false;
```

---

```
        public enum TestEnumTypes
        {
            New = 0,
            Update = 1,
            Discard = 2
        }
```

Then i have a button to add a row that does this:

```
        Table.Rows.Add("NewColumn", TestEnumTypes.New);
```

It adds the row fine, but the enum looks empty.

[Enum column is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz56q.png)

[But the enum works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgiPo.png)

How can i make the enum field show its default value instead of white?

Comment: Have you been able to solve it?